# PHPMailer problem

Tags: php, email

I am new to php. Trying to send confirmation about user upload. I am trying to use PHP Mailer for this. And have the following code but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
// $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
// $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
// $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

// if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
    // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
    // mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo "1";



//Send confirmation email

require_once('_mailClasses/class.phpmailer.php');
include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = 'There is a new online order. Please check your order folder.';
//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.splashoflondon.com";      // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                              // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                           // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.splashoflondon.com";      // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                         // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "adolphus@splashoflondon.com";  // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "correctpassword";                      // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('adolphus@splashoflondon.com', 'Splash of London');

$mail->AddReplyTo("ali@xgreen.co.uk","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "ali@xgreen.co.uk";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");
$mail->Send();
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is it that is not working? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: When i make the ajax request it uploads the file to where i want it to but does not send the confirmation email. I am using vsphp which doesnt have really good debugging tools. it just runs php projects inside visual studio

Comment: Are you getting an error message in your error log? You're also not checking the return value from `$mail->send()`. The example on phpmailers website shows how you can get an error message http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail

Comment: but it has given php errors before for example for re declaring a class so i am assuming it would throw an exception if something was wrong in the code. so i am confused.com really!!

Comment: Are you sure the `include('class.smtp.php')` isn't redeclaring something? Perhaps you could try replacing `include` with `include_once`? Anyway, I suggest you isolate your problem, meaning try to first only send an email and then include the rest of the functionality.

Comment: I will try the suggestions and will post more evidence. thank you guys

Comment: Ok I managed to get proper debugging and the problem is SMTP connection:

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)

Comment: I wouldn't totally mind if you guys give me minus points now. the problem was i set smtp on port 26 instead of 25 :)

Comment: Haha, that's just human. Glad you found the problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are new to PHP, I *highly* recommend you check out basic debugging techniques here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

It's a good read and you'll see your skills as a troubleshooter jump 10-fold.