# How can I use translations in i18next in javascript

Tags: javascript, i18next

I know that I can use i18next to translate languages in html. For example:

`<div data-i18n="someKey"></div>`

But is there a way to somehow use it in JS. For example if I want to do something like

`alert(someKey)`  ?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your setup, you could put it in an arbitrary hidden HTML element and then alert that element's content.

Comment: Downvote for not even bothering to read their official homepage before posting a question

Comment: @XGreen I do not want to disappoint you, but half of your questions can be answered if you would read official documentation. Sometimes people miss something.

Comment: I beg to differ. There is a difference between extraction of an answer from various sections and not scrolling down on the first page

Comment: And the community can upvote you if they think differently ofcourse

Comment: @XGreen you should not go far to find `live` and `on` in [jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431611/jquery-change-event-on-the-iphone), not to mention that it was asked like 100 times here. Or asking questions like [I have 50 lines of code and something does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692777/phpmailer-problem) and I do not even bother making it simpler or debug a little bit by myself. But as it said, people see other's problems, but ignore their own.

Comment: Ok fair enough that PHPMailer one is pretty bad. I will revert. Make an edit to unlock

Comment: @XGreen sometimes people miss simple things. I am mostly trying my best to look at how to do things before posting questions. Sometimes I fail. When I see others answers here, I am disappointed by myself, but it is just for me to learn that I have to look more.

Comment: I accepted the argument. Apologies for quick judgement. Make an edit to unlock the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `alert(t(someKey))` (see http://i18next.com/ at end of page).

Answer (score 1):

Having [read the homepage of the project](http://i18next.com/index.html)...

> ```
> i18n.init(function(t) {
>     // translate nav
>     $(".nav").i18n();
>
>     // programatical access
>     var appName = t("app.name");
> });
> ```

That last part is what you're looking for. It's important to note that that `t` is passed to the `init` callback as a parameter - you can't just blindly call `t()` anywhere ;)